# Extract string value before last delimiter only if it contains numbers

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto, trino

Using Athena, I am trying to extract values that are before last delimiter if the final value contains numbers. If last delimited string doesn't contain numbers, return as is without the delimiter. (:)

| url |
| --- |
| us:retail:legacy:login:21225 |
| us:retail:legacy:funds:44228 |
| us:retail:legacy:success |

**Expected output:**

| new_url |
| --- |
| us:retail:legacy:login |
| us:retail:legacy:funds |
| us:retail:legacy:success |

The query that I used is taking away last delimited string irrespective of whether it contains numbers or not

```
select regexp_replace(url, ':[^:]*$', '') as new_url from table
```

Please help me how to solve this.

Comment: You have two examples in [SQL Server](https://dbfiddle.uk/d4rLJCcc)  and [MySQL](https://dbfiddle.uk/lKPAwfqJ) you could find the equivalent in presto

Comment: @ErgestBasha - Thanks. Could you check the expected output in the post again?

Comment: In MySQL  see example [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/Klp4f8fZ)

Answer (score 0):

You can use negative look-behind ([regex explanation @regex101](https://regex101.com/r/fRHlar/1)):

```sql
-- sample data
with dataset(url) as (
    values ('us:retail:legacy:login:21225'),
        ('us:retail:legacy:funds:44228'),
        ('us:retail:legacy:success'),
        ('us:retail:legacy:success:')
)

-- query
select regexp_replace(url, '(.*)((?<!:):.*\d.*|:$)', '$1')
from dataset;
```

Output:

```
          _col0           
--------------------------
 us:retail:legacy:login   
 us:retail:legacy:funds   
 us:retail:legacy:success 
 us:retail:legacy:success
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! This worked. Could you please explain me what this regex replace is doing?

Comment: @vvazza was glad to help! As for the regex - follow the link, actually you might try even simple pattern - `(.*)(:.*\d.*$|:$)` - in short it splits input in 2 groups, 2nd - should start from `:` and contain a digit or be just `:`.